# How to take an average of certain columns from multiple files?

Tags: import, column, table, averages

I have many text files of tables, 300 rows long and 5 columns across. I can import all the files together as they're all named similarly. I would like to average column 2 of every file together, element by element. Meaning, I want one list of 300 numbers. I keep averaging the whole individual column together, and not the elements from each different column. I might have up to several hundred files, so I'm trying to automate this as much as possible.

Comment: Try: `(Mean[Import[#,"Data"]][[All,2]])& /@ FileNames[...]`

Comment: Consider this contrived example: `(t1 = Table[ConstantArray[i, 10], {i, 15}]) // TableForm` . Each column comes from one file. Then `Mean /@ t1` would give you the mean across each row at a time that (I think) you want.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Is there a way to drop the first row of each file before averaging? Throwing a Drop[...,1] in that command somewhere?

Comment: `Mean /@ Rest@t1` will drop the first row.

Comment: try also `Mean[Rest@Import[#, {"Data", All, 2}] & /@ files]` (where `files` is your list of file names)